# Link_to root_path not working in mail view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add a basic link_to tag to a mail view.

notification.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('S200.gif'), root_path  %>
```

error is `undefined local variable or method 'root_path'` Not very sure why as same bit of code (different image only) works perfectly fine in a normal controller view. root_path is correctly set in routes.

Does the mail view prevent it ?

Comment: I believe the answer is 'yes'. I was just reading the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views) this morning, and my understanding is that you need to use `_url` instead of `_path`.

Comment: you're correct. it fixed the problem. I realise everything in mails should be absolutely linked as it's an independent entity. (actually never thought of using _url instead of _path, good thing to know its possible)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is 'yes'. I was just reading the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views) this morning, and my understanding is that you need to use `_url` instead of `_path`.