# ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `root_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to implement [this](https://myles.eftos.id.au/blog/2013/08/25/track-email-opens-using-a-pixel-tracker-from-rails/#.W0w9zy2mOCR) in order to teach which emails are being sent and opened. But when I create a new user and the emails is being sent I get the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method 'root_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f8d6fe27170>:0x007f8d6fe25168>


 def track(name, email)
    SentEmail.create!(:name => name, :email => email, :sent => DateTime.now)
    url = "#{font_path(:only_path => false)}email/track/#{Base64.encode64("name=#{name}&email=#{email}")}.png"
    raw("")
 end
```

mailer method:

```
def new_user_notification(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: "Welcome")
end
```

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the stack trace of error?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46820022/link-to-root-path-not-working-in-mail-view

Comment: Try replacing `root_path` with `root_url` in your mailer view